# How can i get all "url" elements from the given json

Tags: sql, json, db2, db2-400

When i execute this Statement in my DB2 instance i get an empty column named url. But i except 2 rows in my column. Why isn't it working and how can i fix it?

```
select t.url
  from JSON_TABLE('
     [{"id": "286", "url": "https://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lh3j390T241qfyzelo1_250.jpg"}, 
      {"id": "2dd", "url": "https://24.media.tumblr.com/hA6zECTlEg4sfljwHQf5jm4So1_250.jpg"}
     ]','$[*]' columns (url varchar(100) PATH '$.url')
     ) as t;
```

Comment: Which Db2 version are you on? The query above should return an error

Comment: Hi, im using a DB2 for i Version 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get your syntax to work, but I was able to get the following syntax to work:

```
select *
  from JSON_TABLE('{"table":
                     [{"id": "286", "url": "https://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lh3j390T241qfyzelo1_250.jpg"}, 
                      {"id": "2dd", "url": "https://24.media.tumblr.com/hA6zECTlEg4sfljwHQf5jm4So1_250.jpg"}
                     ]}', 'lax $.table[*]' 
         columns (url VARCHAR(100) PATH 'lax $.url')
 ) as t;
```

There are two things. It appears that the json needs to be enclosed in `{}`, and based on my testing, the array must be named (e.g. `"table": []`).

If the json you must process is an array like the one in your post, you could concatenate `{"table":` to the front, and `}` to the end or your json string. Then it will parse correctly.

**NOTE:** `"table"` is an arbitrary name, and could be anything you wish!

**Additional NOTE:** I was unsure of the importance of `lax` in the path values, and included it just because it was in the IBM [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscajsontable.htm). But, as lax is the default (vs. strict), this SQL works without `lax`.

Turns out that strict is supposed to throw an error if there is a problem with the json, while lax just omits the row. But, if I add strict to the paths in your query, no error is thrown, just no row returned. So, I recommend just omitting both. They just clutter the sql with no discernible benefit.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @jmarkmurphy I finally came up with this one.

```
with cats as(
  select '{"table":' || systools.HTTPGETCLOB('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=20&page=1&size=small',
           cast ('<httpHeader><header name="X-Api-Key" value="b7215c66-a930-4b62-a276-064f956ed64b"/></httpHeader>' as clob(1K))) || '}' as json
    from sysIbm.sysDummy1)
--    
select t.url
  from cats,
       JSON_TABLE(cats.json, 'lax $.table[*]' columns (url VARCHAR(100) PATH 'lax $.url')) as t;
```